# anacron doesnt work as expected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron

Trying to schedule a job to run every day with cron or anacron. Search the forum for resolution but still without any success.

Changing shell=/bin/bash or bin/sh didnt do anything.

My system lubuntu

my anacrontab in /etc/

```
# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly

10      5       myIp    /home/plutus/myIp/public_ip.sh
```

anacron -T doesnt produce any errors.

public-ip.sh is a bash script that runs perfectly if started manually.

```
$ systemctl status anacron
○ anacron.service - Run anacron jobs
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/anacron.service; enabled; pr>
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2024-01-31 10:11:56 EST; 8min >
   Duration: 11min 13.081s
TriggeredBy: ● anacron.timer
       Docs: man:anacron
             man:anacrontab
    Process: 20359 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/anacron -d -q $ANACRON_ARGS (c>
   Main PID: 20359 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1min 7.178s
```

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

EDIT: for testing purposes wrote a simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world" > out.txt
```

force running with sudo anacron -f

didnt make a new file in directory where script should be run from.

line in anacrontab in /etc

```
10    5    test    cd /home/plutus/dir && ./test.sh
```

Comment: You might try specifying full path to out.txt. Also, even though run as sudo, there might be access issue in folder to which file is to be written -- set permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by making switching relative paths in the script to full paths (+1 to @DrMoishe Pippik).
from

```
somefile.txt
```

to

```
$HOME/user/somefile.txt
```

and adding providing full path to environment i.e.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```